# Style first <TD> following row w/certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I need to style the first TD of every row that

- follows a column with a class "header", and
- does not have a colspan set

I don't think I it is possible to do with just CSS, so I assume I need to use jQuery?

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="header">abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sasdas</td>
    <td>21234r</td>
</tr>
```

... something like?

```
$(".header").next("tr>td").css("width","20%");
```

Comment: The columns has class `header` and not the row.

Comment: How about instead of having<br>
`<tr><td class="header">`

Have:

    `<th><td>`

Then you could probably do it in just CSS.

Comment: @PeeHaa Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: @peduarte I have multiple rows with such class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `class` `header` is on a `<td>`, you need to get its parent `<tr>`.
Then get the next `<tr>`, find the first `<td>`. It's kind of ugly really, seems like
you could use `<th>` for you column headers and style them separated from a table cell.

Try this:

```
$(".header").closest('tr').next("tr").find('td:first').not('[colspan]').css("width","20%");
```

Comment: I think you meant `.closest('tr')` and `first` does not accept arguments. You probably want `.next("tr").children('td:first').not('[colspan]')`

Comment: @Gabe I think I'll need to change find('td:first') to find('td:first-child') since I have multiple rows (just one in example), but I think this is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `:not()` is valid CSS3, the `:has()` is jQuery/Sizzle only, the rest is CSS2.

```
$('tr:has(.header) + tr td:first-child:not([colspan])')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use TH's for your header rows. Much cleaner, semantically valid, plus it then makes it so you don't have to use jQuery to take care of all this.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">abc</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sasdas</td>
    <td>21234r</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
td:first-child {
width: 20%; }
```

Regarding only styling the row following the header: it looks like you're just trying to force that one column to be a 20% width? So there'd be no harm in using CSS that applies to it every first-column. [Support for first-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) is pretty solid in the browser landscape today (IE8 needs DOCTYPE declared, but it'll work. polyfil available for older versions if needed).

Comment: But i have multiple rows with that class and there are other nested tables on the page...